# jquery find the mouse click positions in IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a content inside IFRAME, i need to find top and left co-ordinates when mouse click.

i am using the following code to find the top and left co-ordinates, but the top (e.pageY) coordinate giving the wrong position while IFRAME scroll.

```
var iframeDoc = $('#bookcontentHeight').contents().get(0);
// Bind event to iframe document
$(iframeDoc).bind('mouseup', function(e) {                       
    e.preventDefault();                 
    $("#custom-menu").css({
        top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px" 
    }).show(100);
});
```